# How to programmatically use Word's "Compare and Merge Documents..." functionality from C#?

Tags: c#, vsto, word-automation

**Question**

Is it possible to call Word 2003's Tools > Compare and Merge Documents..." function from C# and to get feedback whether any differences were found or not?

**What I have found so far**

It is possible to call the functionality like this. But I don't know how to get feedback whether the were any differences found.

```
    private void CompareAndMergeWithFileB(string fullFilePath)
    {
        string FileName = fullFilePath;
        object MergeTarget = WdMergeTarget.wdMergeTargetSelected;
        object DetectFormatChanges = false;
        object UseFormattingFrom = WdUseFormattingFrom.wdFormattingFromPrompt;
        object AddToRecentFiles = true;

        word.ActiveDocument.Merge(FileName, MergeTarget, DetectFormatChanges, UseFormattingFrom, AddToRecentFiles);
    }
```

Comment: I don't suppose you could compromise by recording the process as a macro in Word, then tweak that to somehow show you any resulting diffs?

Comment: @Darth Continent: I am not sure what you mean. I would like to compare hundreds of documents and I am initially only interested in whether the files are identical or not. Same as in a unit test. If they are not identical, I'd like to click a button which opens a file showing the diff file. Both saving and opening the diff file is not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely. Once the merge is complete, work with the [Revisions collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178864%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to extract details about any changes.